Use Uploadcare only to store the url instead of the image
I do not have access to the website code, I can only use the API in order to solve the following, and I have no idea how Uploadcare is used in the website.
We have 3GB on Uploadcare, and I want to move them to another bucket, and still be able to access them from Uploadcare.
One of the things in my mind is to change the file URL and delete its content or change it to a very small file.

There's no way to move files out of Uploadcare preserving their URLs. Uploadcare CDN URLs refer to files stored in Uploadcare storage.

@AlexChernenko You are correct, it seems that there is no way to change the URL of a file.

I will change the word "approach" to "things in my mind",  it seems the there is an option to connect to AWS S3, but I do not know how I will handle the data stored in Uploadcare while maintaining their uiid.
